# Error building mongo 4.2.12 on debian 10 arm64

Tags: mongodb, arm64

I am trying to build mongo on Debian 10 arm64. I am trying to use the [official documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v4.2.12/docs/building.md) to build but it's failing every time. I am just building mongod using the command:

```
python3 buildscripts/scons.py mongod
```

This results in the following error:

```
Compiling build/opt/mongo/db/logical_clock.o
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/opt/mongo/transport/message_compressor_options_server_gen.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
build/opt/mongo/transport/message_compressor_options_server_gen.o failed: Error 1
```

Previous build try resulted in:

```
**g++:** **fatal error:** Killed signal terminated program cc1plus

compilation terminated.

scons: *** [build/opt/mongo/db/db.o] Error 1

scons: building terminated because of errors.

build/opt/mongo/db/db.o failed: Error 1
```

Online search suggested that I might be using the wrong tool chain:

Comment: Compiling from C++? Which compiler version? You can see the compiler version by running `g++ --version` (if you are on ARM64 machine).

Comment: Probably compilation is consuming too much RAM and when it reaches the threshold, the OS kills the process.